# KVM WinXP guest on physical drive

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ntfs

I want to migrate my Windows VM from VMware player to KVM. All documents I found deal with disk images, however my current VM is installed on real NTFS filesystem, located on separate SATA drive.

Is it possible to configure KVM virtual machine with Windows XP guest, located on physical drive?

Answer (score 2):

Use a P2V solution like `virt-p2v`, found here: http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/

There are many others and that's just an example. While technically it's "virtual", the P2V process will create a disk image that's usable with KVM.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep my VM on physical disk rather then virtual, although I would use your solution as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be a problem - just point the hypervisor to the disk instead of an image. You might want to start with setting the disks up as IDE and using `mergeide.reg` (can be found online) and switching to virtio later on.

Images are normally used because they are so much easier to manage, especially when there are lots of VMs to deal with.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, how to point the hypervisor to the disk?

Comment: in your VM definitions, you simply point to /dev/sdX and use the raw format

Comment: Sounds like what I need. Did you do it? I couldn't find anything about it in the docs.

Comment: yeah, I've used this method before